# MVVM Light with a simple form doing data binding

Tags: c#, forms, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I know there might be more example or answers to this questions but they overwhelm me. I am looking for a no-frills example of a form that uses data binding to populate a collection. This would be using MVVM Light which is great. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx there's links to code in there as well.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this originally but I figured MVVM Light was much simpler to use. I just need to see a form. I am fairly new to the modern world of C# and Blend.